Remove event.target.textContent useForm using MIUI Custom Autocomplete
i try to remove the textContent at MUI Custom Auto complete, the value already deleted but not with the text
heres my snippets code,
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    {fields.map((item, index) => (
        <>
            <Controller
              name={`data[${index}].MasterProductId`}
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: true }}
              render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                <CustomAutocomplete
                  key={index}
                  options={OptionsGroup(masterDataProduct, 'category')}
                  id='autocomplete-grouped'
                  groupBy={option => option.category}
                  getOptionLabel={option => option.name || ''}
                  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                    onChange(+newValue?.id)
                  }}
                  renderInput={params => (
                    <CustomTextField
                      value={item.MasterProductId}
                      {...params}
                      error={Boolean(errors?.data?.[index]?.MasterProductId)}
                      {...(errors?.data?.[index]?.MasterProductId && {
                        helperText: errors?.data?.[index]?.MasterProductId.message
                      })}
                      label='Pilih produk'
                    />
                  )}
                />
              )}
            />

            <IconButton onClick={() => deleteItem(index)} sx={{ color: 'text.primary' }}>
                <Icon icon='tabler:trash' />
            </IconButton>
        <>
    )
</form>

using useForm and useFieldArray
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setError,
    setValue
  } = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
    resolver: yupResolver(schemaNew)
  })

  const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'data'
  })

then this is my fn for remove
  const deleteItem = itemIndex => {
    remove(itemIndex)
  }

I already do useState for the fields and re render using useEffect but the text not change, but the value is deleted. I confuse using control and miui render the component not update when the field is updated. I try to find how to clear value for the CustomTextField but i didnt get it
